# ng-grid - dragging a column header with an image causes Firefox to redirect to the image source location

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

I have put together a quick plunker that demonstrates the problem.

Please open this in firefox and drag the duck column over the other column to reorder them.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dO2uhMKDXQtFbNMkSieR?p=preview

This happens all the time in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE.

I can force it to happen in Chrome if I put break points in the ng-grid.js file on the draggable functionality.   I don't manipulate anything, I just step through the code and it happens like it does in Firefox.   I assume this means it is a timing issue as the debugging alters the execution times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have no idea why the issue happens in Firefox when you have an IMG in the header....

BUT...

I tried setting a background-image on the DIV instead and that seems to have resolved the issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1qF59YExcN1yCDYWlvT?p=preview

.image_duck {
    background-image:url(http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/1799/bathroom/48/duck.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    height: 100px;
    width: 25px; 
    display: block;
}

Comment: Uh, yes. This is quiet shorter and less complicated than my answer. Kudos to you:-)

Answer (score 0):

Totally changed my last answer. Don't know what i tested yesterday, but apparently i didn't work.
So here's my next attempt:

Use this directive

```
app.directive('linkPrevent', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        element.unbind('drop');
        element.bind('drop', function(e) {
          if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          if (e.stopPropogation) {
            e.stopPropogation();
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
});
```

And these Headercell templates

```
  var myHeaderCellTemplate = '<div link-prevent class="ngHeaderSortColumn {{col.headerClass}}" ng-style="{cursor: col.cursor}" ng-class="{ ngSorted: !noSortVisible }">' +
    '<div link-prevent ng-click="col.sort($event)" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" class=""><img  ng-src="http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/1799/bathroom/48/duck.png" alt="{{col.displayName}}"></div>' +
    '<div link-prevent class="ngSortButtonDown" ng-show="col.showSortButtonDown()"></div>' +
    '<div link-prevent class="ngSortButtonUp" ng-show="col.showSortButtonUp()"></div>' +
    '<div link-prevent class="ngSortPriority">{{col.sortPriority}}</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div   ng-show="col.resizable" class="ngHeaderGrip" ng-click="col.gripClick($event)" ng-mousedown="col.gripOnMouseDown($event)"></div>';

  var stdHeaderCellTemplate = '<div link-prevent class="ngHeaderSortColumn {{col.headerClass}}" ng-style="{cursor: col.cursor}" ng-class="{ ngSorted: !noSortVisible }">' +
    '<div link-prevent  ng-click="col.sort($event)" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" class="ngHeaderText" style="height:30px">{{col.displayName}}</div>' +
    '<div link-prevent class="ngSortButtonDown" ng-show="col.showSortButtonDown()"></div>' +
    '<div link-prevent class="ngSortButtonUp" ng-show="col.showSortButtonUp()"></div>' +
    '<div link-prevent  class="ngSortPriority">{{col.sortPriority}}</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div ng-show="col.resizable" class="ngHeaderGrip" ng-click="col.gripClick($event)" ng-mousedown="col.gripOnMouseDown($event)"></div>';
```

and these columnDefs

```
columnDefs: [{
  field: 'name',
  headerCellTemplate: myHeaderCellTemplate
}, {
  field: 'age',
  headerCellTemplate: stdHeaderCellTemplate
}]
```

Now this works in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/68X7TtnJKYo8klhfiJdU?p=preview) (Yep, lazy mainguy did a thorough test this time. Dragged it everywhere)

Note:
This will prevent the default on every drop event.

I assigned it all over the place to be sure there are no elements left that are, although very small (sort button), capable of linking to a new target.

Be aware that the size of ngHeaderText is set to 30px to fill the whole header. If the height does not fit, there might be a small gap where default linking can pass through (sneaky bastich!)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately your plunker still has the same error as in the OP when moving the duck column under Firefox.